# Osgi Import-Package: Same package names but two different bundles

Tags: osgi

I have an eclipse app E that uses bundle B1(version=1.45.1) and bundle B2(version=1.15.2)

The app E has a class that imports class b1 of bundle B1.

B1 has it in its export-Package section
Export-Package: x.y.z.b;version="1.45.1"

The app E also uses a jar that has Export-Package with the same above package name
Export-Package: x.y.z.b;version="1.15.2"

Even though these are two different jars, the package names are the same. Now the jars are not resolved here. How do I handle this scenario?

We are planning to keep only Import-Package. Hence Require-Bundle will not be an option.

Comment: The bundles exporting the package need to be resolved. Since E imports the package, I would think the OSGi framework would attempt to resolve the providers (exporters) of the package. Is there some reason the bundles exporting the package are not resolve or cannot be resolved?

Comment: They are all in resolved state but app throws class not found exception for class b1 of bundle B1.